# DataTable.Select() - Not Returning All DataRows

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a Parts datatable kept in viewstate that I bind to an ASP.net gridview. One of the columns in the Parts table is Part Id. When the user chooses to edit a part field, I use DataTable.Select() to find the current part they are editing using the below code:

```
DataRow row = _Parts.Select(string.Format("[Part Id] = {0}", partId))[0];
```

Where Part Id is always an integer (and yes I know, the statement is not well written).

So as the user adds parts, the Part Id starts at 0 and increments. In one case the user added 13 parts. When I run the aforementioned line of code, an exception is thrown because the array returned does not have any elements (specifically it does not have a part with id = 12).

So I did a loop through all the rows in `_Parts` and found that there are 13 parts, including a row with a Part Id of 12 (the last one). The Select doesn't find it though. In fact it only finds Parts 1-10 (or indices 0-9), and this is where I'm stuck. The part exists in the `_Parts` object, but select can't find it. The only thing I could think of is that it is a double digit integer, but it should work the same way shouldn't it? Why can it only find indices 0-9?

**EDIT**: Since users have asked how I add parts, here you are:

```
        DataRow dr = _Parts.NewRow();

        dr["Part No"] = txtPartNo.Text;
        dr["Qty"] = txtQty.Text;
        dr["Description"] = txtDescription.Text;
        dr["Vendor"] = txtVendor.Text;
        dr["Vendor Part"] = txtVendorPart.Text;
        dr["Cost"] = (cost.ToString("C2") == "$0.00") ? "" : cost.ToString("C2");
        dr["PO Number"] = txtPONumber.Text;
        dr["Delivery Date"] = txtDeliveryDate.Text;
        dr["Part Notes"] = txtPartNotes.Text;
        dr["Total Cost"] = (total.ToString("C2") == "$0.00") ? "" : total.ToString("C2");

        if (_Parts.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            // Initialize ID at 0.
            dr["Part Id"] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // ID is count of rows.
            dr["Part Id"] = _Parts.Rows.Count;
        }

        _Parts.Rows.Add(dr);
        _Parts.AcceptChanges();
        gvParts.DataSource = _Parts;
        gvParts.DataBind();
```

Comment: to diagnose, i will try DataRow row = _Parts.Select("[Part Id] = " + partId)[0];

Comment: How do you add a new row into this _Parts datatable? Do call the method AcceptChanges() on the table after you add or edit data? If you have done so, please post your code of editing and adding new row.

Comment: Does your view only show 10 at a time?  It sounds like it's only filtering the current page, not the entire dataset.

Comment: On a separate note, your `if` statement is superfluous, as it does the same thing as the else does.

Comment: @uowzd01 No luck with that.

Comment: @WeryNguyen See code above.

Comment: @KyleW the grid shows only 5 rows at a time, so it has 3 pages. and thanks for catching the if statement issue

Comment: There is a simple workaround (loop through rows and find one that matches the id) but I'm still baffled as to why the Select function can't find it....